# How in Oracle kill user session silent or reproduce error 17410?

Tags: oracle, session, jdbc, kill, silent

I need to test robustness of my application for problem with network. But I don't have access to network physically. I have only access to Oracle as SYS. Does it possible may be silent kill user session so when application try to get data from connection jdbc driver will generate error 17410 ?

```
oracle: No more data to read from socket
```

When I try to kill session by sid - oracle send alert about killed session and this is not 17410 error.

Answer (score 1):

You can raise any error code with PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT.

```
DECLARE
  e_no_more_data EXCEPTION
  pragma exception_init( e_no_more_data , -17410  );
BEGIN
  RAISE e_no_more_data;
END;
/
```

Don't know if it really simulates the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to only the database and you know the SID and Serial of the session you are trying to kill, you can issue

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#';
```

Check this link for more options.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions.php

Comment: yes, I use this - but jdbc driver on client part receive alert about killed session something like ORA-00028: your session has been killed . I need receive error 17410

Comment: Sorry, I am not following you correctly. You need to somehow simulate 17410 error?

Comment: Yes, I cannot disconnect physically because database and client on remote servers. But sometimes happen network problems. I have fixed client application but need to check if my fix works.